# Upload multiple log files per Hudson build step

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugins

We're considering moving to Hudson, and currently have build steps that write 2 files (say, a log file and an audit file), and I would like both of them to be viewable for each step (kind of like the Console Output thing, simply for other files).

I couldn't find a plugin that seemed to do this from the short descriptions. What's the way for doing this in Hudson?

Comment: let us know what solution you choose and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok to put them in the output than you can simply add another build step that prints these files to the output (use cat (linux/unix) or type (windows)).

**EDIT** I just a new idea.

Use the archive feature of your job for the two files. They will appear as build artifacts on the status page of the job, if you click on the link you can see them in the browser. That should solve your problem.

Comment: It is just one build step, you can write whole scripts in the 'Execute Windows batch command' or 'execute shell' build steps. Hudson will create a temporary file to execute it. You can also add comments or echos to do that. Have a look at the Log Parser plugin (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Log+Parser+Plugin) to make your output more readable.

Comment: @abyx, 10 build steps sounds like something that should be refactored into a build script instead of just stored in Hudson (or whatever CI system).

Comment: @Dave Imagine a framework with 10 sub modules. We like to run each one's tests in a different step, so team members can recognize quickly who broke the build.

Comment: Are you talking about different build steps or different jobs?

Comment: Go with the build script and mark the beginnings of each section with a unique string. Than you can use the log parser plugin (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Log+Parser+Plugin). Define a rule for the info category to find the unique strings for the sections and the plugin will organize the rest for you. Disclaimer: I havn't used that plugin yet, but plan to test it soon.